# it is comment to use str(self.value) inside __str__ enum

Tags: python-3.x, enums

is it good idea to convert enum self.value to string inside of `__str__`
try to get everyone's opinion if I should add str(self.value) or just self.value to get value from each key in enum. One benefit is force **str** result as string. so when some stupid engineer put `ny = 10234` I can still get string type value

```
from enum import Enum
class City(Enum):
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)
    ny = 'New York'
    ca = 'New California'
    nj = 'New Jersey'
    RI = 'Rhode Island'
City.RI
```

Comment: I suggest `repr` instead of `str`

Comment: any particular reason for it? two purpose I would like to reach 1: i do not need to use enum.key.value to get value 2:i can always get string type

Comment: take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr

Answer (score 0):

`__str__` must return a `str`.  If you are going to override the default Enum `__str__` method, then you must return a `str` from it.

Also, `__str__` should return a nice, human readable string -- something you might drop into text -- not the output from `repr()`, which should be used for debugging and other low-level tasks.

Comment: correct..but my concern is if I should add str(self.value) to convert whatever value match with key..to avoid the error `__str__ returned non-string (type int)`

Comment: @jacobcan118: if you are overriding `__str__` to return the value of the Enum member, and that value is or may be a non-`str`, then yes,  use `str()` on it, or some other method that will convert the value to a `str`.